# How to implement a bidirectional unique index across multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql

Okay i know i can do this in the application layer, which is probably the easiest thing to do, but just to make sure that no errors water down to the DB, i have a serious question

I have two columns X and Y, each to store two integers (either A or B in any of the columns). Is it possible to have a unique index constraint such that, in no instance should we have

1. Column X with A and Column Y with B
2. Column X with B and Column Y with A

I'll give a scenario

I have two users, userA has id 678498 and userB has id 679879. Both users are about to play a 2 player game which requires that a new record for this session be stored in a table (tbl_chalenger). To do so, i have a table with columns "host" and "challenger".

I have a unique constrain added to tbl_challenger as

```
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_PARTICIPANTS` (`host`,`challenger`)
```

Branding users a host or challenger is basically dependent on who initiated the game. So if userA initiates the game we have an query as follows

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_challenger` VALUES(678498 , 679879);
```

which creates a new record, Sadly though, if at the same time userB attempts to initiate a game with user A, we get

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_challenger` VALUES(679879, 678498 );
```

Which creates a new unwanted row, of the same participants. This irrespective of the UNIQUE key constraint.

So my question is how to have a constraint that is bidirectional?, such that "host-challenger" as well as "challenger-host" cannot have the same data pair

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In mysql the only way I can think of is to add a couple of utility columns like

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_challenger (
  host int,
  challenger int,
  u0 int, u1 int
);
```

and add a couple of triggers that set `u0` and `u1` to the least and greatest of the two:

```
CREATE TRIGGER uinsert BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_challenger
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.u0 = LEAST(NEW.host,NEW.challenger),
  NEW.u1 = GREATEST(NEW.host,NEW.challenger);
CREATE TRIGGER uupdate BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_challenger
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.u0 = LEAST(NEW.host,NEW.challenger),
  NEW.u1 = GREATEST(NEW.host,NEW.challenger);
```

then you add a unique index on `(u0,u1)`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueness ON tbl_challenger(u0,u1);
```

And now you will get an error trying to insert duplicate pair regardless of the order.

On a decent RDBMS like `PostgreSQL` you would be able to use index on expression:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueness ON tbl_challenger
    ( LEAST(host,challenger), GREATEST( host,challenger) );
```

So, switch before it's too late ;-)

Comment: Excellent works perfectly!! Yeah, just using MySQL because its an extension for an application which uses only MySQL and no time to write a whole new abstraction layer for other DBMS, but will surely look into that when i get some more time. Thanks very much hacker

Comment: You're welcome. I knew that changing is not likely an option, but I had to say it;-) And then again, with a bit of imagination, even mysql can be put to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that "out of the box", like using a UNIQUE index or whatever stuff like this.

Still, you might probably be able to implement that kind of check using a trigger, triggered before inserts and updates.

I've not worked with triggers for quite sometime, and it wasn't on MySQL, so I won't be able to give you any example, but here's the relevant page of the manual : [12.1.19. CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

*As a sidenote : this kind of constraint is, like you said, generally implemented on the application side.*

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, the triggers worked just as wanted! Thank you!