# How to search for a tuple in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `friend` INT NOT NULL ,
  `status` INT(1) NOT NULL ,
  INDEX `user_id_fk_idx` (`userid` ASC) ,
  INDEX `friend_id_fk_idx` (`friend` ASC) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`, `friend`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userid` )
    REFERENCES `network`.`users` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `friend_id_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend` )
    REFERENCES `network`.`users` (`userid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When I want to insert a new tuple in this table, I want to check if that tuple already exists or not.

Example: when i insert (1,2,0) in table it must run if and only if (1,2,*) or (2,1,*) is not present in table. Or if i search for tuple (1,2,*) in table it must search for (1,2,*) and (2,1,*) and give results back.

Currently i am running two queries for this, can this be combined in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say `a` and `b` are your userID's, then this will give `TRUE` if either of the tuples exists, `FALSE` if not

```
SELECT COUNT(*) > 0
FROM friends
WHERE
    (friends.userid = a AND friends.friend = b)
OR  (friends.userid = b AND friends.friend = a)
```

You can also construct a bidirectional relation from your table

```
SELECT friends.userid AS userid, friends.friend AS friend FROM friends
UNION ALL
SELECT friends.friend AS userid, friends.userid AS friend FROM friends
```

IF you want to do it all in one `INSERT` query you'll need to use `INSERT ... SELECT` combined with `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in the `SELECT part`. [Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5b05/3)

```
INSERT INTO friends (userid, friend)
SELECT a,b FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT friends.userid
    FROM friends
    WHERE
        (friends.userid = a AND friends.friend = b)
    OR  (friends.userid = b AND friends.friend = a)
)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more about Bidirectional Relation?

Comment: And how do implement such thing upon insertion?

Comment: Can i add one more question on this query, Is it possible to know which part of query returned true. Example  something like this "select status,@var from friends where @ var:=(userid=4 and friend=2) or @ var:=(friend=4 and userid=2 )"

Comment: Do you want that in the `INSERT` or in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: I got my second problem solved by using CASE, thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to follow the "bi-directional" example here (it's pretty good)

[How to implement a bidirectional unique index across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450883/how-to-implement-a-bidirectional-unique-index-across-multiple-columns)

Once you've got this in place you can either

1. **SELECT** and if nothing there **INSERT** your new data.

or

2. **INSERT** and catch error if one is thrown because the data is already there.